# Length attribute is different from object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, content-length

When I run `console.log(myArray)` I get an Array Object and I can see all the elements with a length of 11 in the Firebug window.

If I run `console.log(myArray.length)` immediately after the above statement, it returns 0

If I do `console.log(myArray[0])`  immediately after the above statement, it returns undefined

Not sure exactly what is going on here. Does the length attribute behave differently than simply calling the object.

Comment: you have to share your code :) no one can guess what are you doing

Comment: @martinezjc: Sorry, but I did guess :-)

Comment: It would have helped your question a lot if you had posted what the object looks like.